# How to fill a ListFillRange property of an ActiveX ComboBox with a formula

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Is it possible to fill a ListFillRange property of an activex combobox with a formula to populate it with the results of this formula ? if yes, how ?

Here is the formula that I want to fill my combobox with it :

> =OFFSET('List of Clients'!A2,0,0,COUNTA('List of Clients'!A:A)-1)

I am trying to fill my combobox with this formula, but it's not working (if I add a formula the ListFillRange property stay blank like if I didn't add anything to it), so I am wondering about the type of data that this property accept. ***Does it accept only strings ?***

If yes, ***how to fill it with formula's results ?*** ***If not what kind of data does it accept ?***

In this example, my above formula will bring back a list of clients that I want to add to my combobox, how to do that ?

Here is a part of the code that I am using the fill the combobox which is not working

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim xCombox As OLEObject
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xStr As String
    
    
    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
      
    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
            Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
            Cancel = True
            xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1

            'The Formula1 contains the formula that I provided above 
            '=OFFSET('List of Clients'!A2,0,0,COUNTA('List of Clients'!A:A)-1)

            xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1) 'I tried to keep or remove the "=" I got same result
            If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
                            
            With xCombox         
            .ListFillRange = xStr 'If I do this, the .ListFillRange stay blank 
            End With
    End If
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Fill a Combo Box Using Formula Evaluation

- I am not quite sure how you are planning to apply this using the Worksheet SelectionChange event (`Cancel = True` doesn't belong here) so I'm presenting a solution outside of it. Surely you will manage to apply it successfully.

```vb
Sub PopulateComboBox()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' The combo box is in this worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!

    Dim EvalStr As String
    EvalStr = "OFFSET('List of Clients'!A2,0,0,COUNTA('List of Clients'!A:A)-1)"
    ' The equal sign (=) is optional, so you can use '.Formula1' as-is.
    
    Dim cmb As OLEObject: Set cmb = ws.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
    
    cmb.Object.List = Application.Transpose(ws.Evaluate(EvalStr))
    ' ws.Evaluate(EvalStr) - returns a 2D one-based single-column array
    ' Appication.Transpose() - converts to a 1D array suitable for the combo box

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help, I will try your suggestions once at work and will let you know. To answer your question, forget about the event itself, I am trying to make an autocomplete validation list based on a code that I saw on the net and my problem is not where I place the code and the event itself as I said, I posted just a part of the code not all of it to make things short for helpers. You said that combo accept 1D array, what does it accept other than arrays ? it's either strings or a 1D array ? can you explain more to me ? The Evaluate will get us the result of the formula right?

Comment: `=Offset(...)` 'evaluates to a single-column range' (I don't know the correct terminology) but you can't use it with `.ListFillRange`. `Worksheet.Evaluate` will return the values from the range in a 2D array. `Application.Transpose` will transpose the values from the 2D array to a 1D array. `.Object.List` will write the values from the 1D array to the combo box in one go. Get more familiar with it by reading through this [great combo box article](https://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Fill_combobox_listbox_en.html).

Comment: thanks again. I tried to use your code, I get the following error : Run-time Error '381': Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index, it seems that the Active X Combobox, doesn't have this List property ?

Comment: `xCombox.List` doesn't work, `xCombox.Object.List` does. Or e.g. `Sheet1.TempCombo.List`. The intelli-sense will tell you if there is a List property. More importantly, when there is no List property there is another error (438). In this case, something is wrong with the right side of the equation (*Invalid property array index*).

Comment: yes, I made a simple copy paste of Your code to try it without even integrating it yet in my code, I just copy pasted it your code and called the function and added an error trap to see why it's not working and found that this line : cmb.Object.List = Application.Transpose(ws.Evaluate(EvalStr)) 
is giving the error 381. is it working on your PC ? sure you used an ActiveX Combobox and not the forms Combobox ?

Comment: The code for a forms combo box is quite different. What did you put in `EvalStr`? `Evaluate` may be producing something invalid. Did you set the correct worksheet?

Comment: Your right, I am sorry, I had a spelling mistake in the sheet name, I used Clientt instead of Client in my sheet name, now your code works, I will try to include it into my code and let you know the final result, thanks and sorry for this spelling mistake.

Comment: Btw, do we have the right to provide a link for a code example outside Stackoverflow ? if yes I am trying to do this : https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-data-validation-drop-down-list-autocomplete/  so that you will understand more what I need and maybe you will have a better idea than this

Comment: I browsed shortly through it and it seems cool. Even cooler is that you're making an improvement on it. That's the spirit.

Comment: Exactly, thanks a lot, and are we Okay, that in my case I should not use the ListFillRange like the example above but the Object.List Like you suggested ?

Comment: I am getting a problem with the EVALUATE FUNCTION if the function is not in english. I have to covert the functions to english or there is a way to make it accept any Excel function in different langages ?

Comment: I am still getting sometimes errors with xCombox.Object.List, for example I created a button to clear the combobox, I made a copy paste of the code, I get an error like the one i mentioned above : Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index